# access pentaho in ssl

Tags: pentaho

I have some Pentaho reports which are accessed through the tomcat server as http://localhost:8080/report_name like this. I want to implement https instead of http. Probably implement SSL on the Pentaho reports so that all the reports are accessed through https:// followed by rest of the urls. How is this achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pentaho in its default configuration runs in a Tomcat container, and therefore the Tomcat documentation contains everything you need to make the switch to SSL.

Follow the steps from 
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/ssl-howto.html
and 
http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/ServerDoc1x/01.+Enabling+SSL+in+Tomcat

Comment: Hi Thomas, I read the docuemnt. But I am just confirming whether my understandings are correct to make it to work.
Add a keystroke to tomcat server. Could you please let me know under which folder i need to add this. Im in windows OS. Do i have to locate some directory in cmd prompt and enter the keystorke commamd?
Once i Added the key stroke, whether i need to do anything with the pentaho installation files. Please explain. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make changes into your server.xml file into tomcat/conf folder.

```
 <Connector URIEncoding="UTF-8" port="8081" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
               connectionTimeout="20000" 
               proxyPort="443" scheme="https" secure="true"
              proxyName="xxx.xxx..com" />
```

Then if you are using some CAS then also you need to make changes into applicationcontest-spring-security-cas.xml file
and last one web.xml file .

Then restart the server and try on https